# Tweet to past - How to have the greatest influence?

Tags: alternate-history, time-travel

A secret community has existed throughout the written history of humanity, but now in contemporary era is on the verge of destruction. They have invented a time machine, but only have enough energy to send one message to the past. In addition, time travel paradoxes mean that they cannot directly affect their own past actions or what happens to them, so sending the lottery numbers to your past self is not going to work. (Consider this more as a timey-wimey limitation, the story is not about describing a rigorous model of time travel.)

As a final "all or nothing" gamble, they have decided to send a message that will change the world's economic and political situation as much as possible, and just hope that the result will be better for themselves.

To summarize:

- One message to one person in history, maximum length 140 characters.
- Message is in English, no need to worry about translation for now.
- Destination time from 4000 BCE to 2015 CE.
- Message will be delivered by whatever means were relevant at the time, e.g. courier, telegram or snail-mail.
- Goal is maximal change in modern day (2015) economic and political situation.

**To whom and what should they tweet?**

Comment: Send a message to Hippocrates and tell him to add "wash your hands with soap and warm water before operating" to the Hippocratic Oath. If he does that, the rest of history from that point out will be changed forever.

Comment: For a take on this concept ( although it goes further as it continues ) you could read Orson Scott Card's _Pastwatch_ which explores it to some length.

Comment: [XKCD 567: Urgent Mission](http://xkcd.com/567/) has the answer.

Comment: I have to say that if this is an electronic message (tweet or text) you would have to send it back to a time when we have sufficiently advanced technology to read it. Sending a text to Hippocrates would achieve nothing.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan OP *did* say "Message will be delivered by whatever means were relevant at the time, e.g. courier, telegram or snail-mail".

Comment: Thanks for all the great ideas so far! :)I was afraid that this would be considered off-topic. It is not easy to say what kinds of "idea generation" are too wide and non-objective.

Answer (score 7):

As a general requirement you want the receiver to actually act on information coming from unknown source. That has sub-requirements.

1. The receiver must understand the significance of the information instantly. That being the time most people use to think about information coming from unknown sources. This kind of implies literacy.
2. The receiver must be willing to act on the information. Either the cost of action is trivial **or** the information makes sense as soon as pointed out **or** the cost of verifying the information is trivial compared to possible gain. And yes, there must be some direct gain for the receiver.
3. The receiver must be able to act on the information. The receiver must understand the information, form a plan of action based on it and then perform the actions. The last is usually understood, but given the character limit, much must be left to the personal ability of the receiver.

Usually it is condition 2, that is difficult. Usually in the turning points there an "easily correctable" mistake was made, the people were warned. Information about Pearl Harbor was available, Caesar was presumably warned of assassination, and so on. The problem is that such risks are always present and unsupported rumours abound. Most people capable of taking decisive action are excellent at filtering out such background noise.

Also most decisive moments are related to war or violence and the results of meddling with such are difficult to predict. The most likely result is nothing. There are points where the history apparently was changed by chance, often of one person dying. But even then the big picture might not have changed a lot. Or it might have changed in a way you could not predict. Or depend on assumptions that might or might not be true. For example if you warned Jesus of the betrayal by Judas, you might end up with nothing happening, if the truth was that Jesus already knew. Which is quite possible as he was deliberately acting out a prophecy.

Similarly most groundbreaking inventions really take more than 140 to explain. Gunpowder, the plow, advances in sail plans, some construction techniques might be simple enough to explain and make a big difference, but 140 is not really enough to have any reason to believe proper use would be made.

So basically you are relying on the receiver figuring it out. Thus the logical receiver is [Hero of Alexandria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_of_Alexandria). You'd still have no control of anything happening, but he probably would figure it out. I'd say send him the formula for gunpowder. Hero would be able to build some amazing toys with it. And once gunpowder was known, it would inevitably change the power balance between civilization and nomads. And the nature of warfare and eventually economy.

Comment: "And once gunpowder was known, it would inevitably change the power balance between civilization and nomads. And the nature of warfare and eventually economy."  Almost certainly, though the question remains:  would the change have been for the better?

Answer (score 1):

Go as far back as you can. Change one butterfly and chaos ensures that the present will  be utterly different when history runs again with the small peturbation.

Just make sure it's not a civilisation that will die out before change can ripple beyond it.

It would be funny if the careful message to the target doesn't work, but the message delivery boy, in changing his path, causes a peturbation that diverges in subtle and obscure ways until finally making someone famous change a pivital moment, thousands of years later.

The story could follow the minor effect, each domino, in vignettes through history in a Rube Goldberg pathway.